# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Just I did my web pack upgrade from 2.x to 4.x. By doing npm install i was getting the following error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader'
```

Following the [github thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1083) , i added the following lines in webpack.config.json

```
 resolveLoader: {   root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules') }
```

But i got the following error ,

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.resolveLoader has an unknown property 'modulesDirectories'. These properties are valid: object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
```

babel-loader version is 7.1.4 . Webpack upgrade has introduced this error. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Can you post your webpack config?

Answer (score 2):

Just install the module:

`npm install babel-loader`

or

`yarn add babel-loader`

I got this problem fixed by running the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you install this "babel-loader" 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader

```
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js'),
        ],
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
            presets: ["es2015"],
            plugins: [
                ["babel-plugin-root-import", {
                    "rootPathSuffix": "src/js"
                }],
                [
                    "transform-runtime", {
                        "helpers": false,
                        "polyfill": false,
                        "regenerator": true,
                        "moduleName": "babel-runtime"
                    }
                ],
                "transform-object-assign", "transform-function-bind"
            ]
        },
        // options for the loader
    }}
```

Comment: I got the following error ,

Module parse failed: Unexpected token 
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.